# Currying issues with F#. What is the right way to attach functions to the type?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I can't understand what is wrong with following bit of code:

```
let toClass (problem:Problem<'a>) (classID:int) (items:'a list) =
        let newFreqTable = (problem.FreqTables.[classID]).count items
        { problem with FreqTables = newFreqTable :: (problem.FreqTables |> List.filter (fun i -> i.ClassID <> classID)) }
type Problem<'a> when 'a : equality with member this.toClass (classID:int) (items:list<'a>) = toClass this classID items
```

I have a `Problem` type which is nothing but a way to group up any number of `FreqTables` - short for "Frequency tables". So `toClass` method just takes appropriate freqTable (by `classID` argument) and returns a new one - with calculated given items.

```
let typeIndependentCall = toClass p 0 ["word"; "word"; "s"] // this works perfectly

let typeDependentCall = typeIndependentCall.toClass 1 ["word"; "s"] 
// gives an error: "One or more of the overloads of this method has 
// curried arguments. Consider redesigning these members to take 
// arguments in tupled form".
```

I am pretty new to F# and functional programming. What is the right way to attach behavior to my type?

Comment: Use `member` see docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/classes

Comment: I really recommend join to the [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/). Recently was open #ru-general channel (if you prefer russian language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In F# there are 2 main ways of passing arguments to a function: curried and tupled. The curried form is what you are using in your code above, and has a few key benefits, the first and foremost being partial application.

For example, instead of thinking of

```
fun add a b = a + b
```

as a function that takes in 2 arguments and returns a value, we can think of it as a function of one argument that returns *a function that with one argument*. This is why the type signature of our function is

```
Int -> Int -> Int
```

or, more clearly,

```
Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

However, when overloading methods, we can only use the tupled argument form

```
(Int, Int) -> Int
```

The reason for this is for optimization, as is discussed [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsyme/2009/05/20/detailed-release-notes-for-the-f-may-2009-ctp-update-and-visual-studio-2010-beta1-releases/)

To get your code to work, use

```
type Problem<'a> when 'a : equality with member this.toClass (classID:int, items:list<'a>) = toClass this classID items
```

and call it like such:

```
let typeDependentCall = typeIndependentCall.toClass(1, ["word"; "s"])
```